# Dividing both sides of a differential equation by a variable.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question specifically states-

> Find the equation of a curve passing through the point $(0,1)$ given that the slope of the tangent to the curve at any point $(x,y)$ is equal to the sum of $x$-coordinate and the product of the $x$-coordinate and $y$-coordinate of the point.

My solution:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}= x + xy
$$
or, $\frac{1}{x} (\frac{dy}{dx})= 1 + y$ [ dividing both sides by x]

or, $\frac{1}{1+y}dy$= $x$  $dx$

now integrating both sides

$\log(1+y)= x^2/2 + C$

But my general eqn of the curve seems to be wrong. I think I made the mistake while dividing by x.

I know about dividing both sides of an algebraic equation by a variable and the precautions needed there. But I'm new to differential equations and not sure how dividing by variables work here. I have, however, solved a previous problem by dividing by a variable, namely-

$\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{2x-y}{x+y}$

[ I divided numerator and denominator of RHS by x and and put y/x=v]

But the first problem, I couldn't solve by diving variables. So... why?

Update: My textbook used the method of Integrating factors and got a different solution making me think my solution was wrong. Turns out both versions are equivalent to each other and my solution was correct too.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{1+y}=xdx$, you re-arranged wrongly.

Comment: sorry, changed now

Comment: What is the solution in the textbook? Maybe you have an equivalent expresssion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think your solution is incorrect? As far I can tell, you did everything correctly. One way to confirm this is to note that you can change

$$\log(1+y)= x^2/2 + C \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

by taking both sides to the power of $e$, to get

$$y + 1 = C_1 e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

where $C_1 = e^C$. Now, using the initial condition of $(0, 1)$, we get that

$$1 + 1 = C_1 e^0 \Rightarrow C_1 = 2 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Thus, your solution would be

$$y = 2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

If you wish to confirm the original differential equation works, if you differentiate each side wrt $x$, you get

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(2x\right)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} = 2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Using that $y + 1 = 2e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ gives

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x\left(y + 1\right) = x + xy \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

This is your original equation.

Comment: Update: My textbook used the method of Integrating factors and got a different solution making me think my solution was wrong. Turns out both versions are equivalent to each other and my solution was correct too.

Answer (score 2):

From $\log(1+y)=\frac{x^2}2+C$, you get that $y=e^{x^2/2+C}-1$. Let us test this. You have then$$y'(x)=xe^{x^2/2+C}=x\left(e^{x^2/2+C}-1\right)+x=xy(x)+x.$$So, yes, what you got *is* a solution.

Comment: Update: My textbook used the method of Integrating factors and got a different solution making me think my solution was wrong. Turns out both versions are equivalent to each other and my solution was correct too.

Comment: I'm glad to know that.